# Power BI : Why does the Incremental refresh set me an error in my data model?

Tags: powerbi

In my Pbix file, I got two tables set on incremental refresh, with a relationship many to one.

In my power query I deleted the duplicates of the primary key column of the one side.

However when I publish it to the workspace and refresh the dataset, there is an error : the primary key column used for the relationship on the one side has duplicated value.

I don't understand since my power query should delete the duplicated values.

The data source is a PowerBIDatamart.

Somebody has a clue why this error is coming up ?

Thanks,

Max

I tried to add another primary key column (index) for the relationship on both side without any success (same error).

Answer (score 0):

Two things could cause this:

1. Incorrect Filters for Date based on RangeStart and RangeEnd.
   What do you have for the date filter? Should be `[Date] >= RangeStart and [Date] <= RangeEnd`
2. [Problem: Refresh fails because of duplicate values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-troubleshoot#problem-refresh-fails-because-of-duplicate-values)
   With incremental refresh, a partition is created per date block. So even if you are removing duplicates, you are only doing it for that partition.

Comment: Thank you Sam for your time and advice. I made sure that RangeStart and RangeEnd are porperly set (in this case I set it the same day sept 5th 2023).  Now it's interesting about the removing duplicates for all partition. How could we do that ?  Thanks